# How to find common variables in different data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have several data frames with similar (but not identical) series of variables (columns). I want to find a way for R to tell me what are the common variables across different data frames.

Example:

```
`a <- c(1, 2, 3)
b <- c(4, 5, 6)
c <- c(7, 8, 9)
df1 <- data.frame(a, b, c)
b <- c(1, 3, 5)
c <- c(2, 4, 6)
df2 <- data.frame(b, c)`
```

With `df1` and `df2`, I would want some way for R to tell me that the common variables are `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1)** For 2 data frames:

```
intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
## [1] "b" "c"
```

To get the names that are in df1 but not in df2:

```
setdiff(names(df1), names(df2))
```

**1a)** and for any number of data frames (i.e. get the names common to all of them):

```
L <- list(df1, df2)
Reduce(intersect, lapply(L, names))
## [1] "b" "c"
```

**2)** An alternative is to use `duplicated` since the common names will be the ones that are duplicated if we concatenate the names of the two data frames.

```
nms <- c(names(df1), names(df2))
nms[duplicated(nms)]
## [1] "b" "c"
```

**2a)** To generalize that to n data frames use `table` and look for the names that occur the same number of times as data frames:

```
L <- list(df1, df2)
tab <- table(unlist(lapply(L, names)))
names(tab[tab == length(L)])
## [1] "b" "c"
```

Comment: I'm trying to get variables not common to all DFs. In the given example, using `setdiff` in 1a produces the expected "a". Add variable "d" to df2 and `setdiff` does not produce "a", "d". Negation in 2a, `tab!=length(L)` solved my problem, thanks. I am trying to understand why `setdiff` doesn't work with lapply.

Comment: `setdiff` gives elements in first argument that are not in the second.  It does not give elements of the second argument that are not in the first. This gives the names that are not in every data frame.  `L <- list(df1, df2); nms <- lapply(L, names); setdiff(Reduce(union, nms), Reduce(intersect, nms))`
`

Answer (score 4):

Use `intersect`:

```
intersect(colnames(df1),colnames(df2))
```

**OR**

We can also check for the colname using `%in%`:

```
colnames(df1)[colnames(df1) %in% colnames(df2)]
```

Output:

```
[1] "b" "c"
```